# How to create MBR bootable Windows USB installer from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, mbr, windows-installation

In a Windows machine I have used Rufus for creating a USB installer for Windows.
How can I do the same from Linux?

I want to create a Windows USB installer (for Linux UNetbootin and many more tools work fine).
For UEFI boot, simple copy pasting in FAT partition works.
But I could not find solution for creating MBR bootable Windows USB.

Comment: There's essentially a duplicate question on ServerFault, which should help you out. The whole process is pretty much the same since Windows 7: http://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux Also did you try whether you're not just missing the active/bootable flag for your partition?

Answer (score 1):

https://thornelabs.net/2013/06/10/create-a-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive-in-linux.html

ms-sys does the magic of writing boot record.

Comment: For the record, ms-sys is actually what Rufus uses behind the scenes to install the boot records, so, yeah, you should be able to achieve the same with ms-sys on Linux...